# Window aspect ratio varies depending on window size

Tags: windows, winapi, aspect

I'm trying to understand how a program is determining the new width/height when resizing it.

One would think it's merely an aspect ratio like 4:3 (which would lead to a 1.333333 ish value) however as you can see in this gif, the divition width/height throws a very different result depending on the window size.

https://gyazo.com/f3d514b9bf51f49899612090868ec140

I have seen many programs behave like this. Any idea what the algorithm is behind this?

Thanks!

Comment: The "algorithm" is: `new_height = new_width * arbitrary_aspect_ratio`. Unless there's something I'm missing.

Comment: I'm looking for something better than "arbitrary" if possible haha

Comment: The point is, the author of a program can use **any** aspect ratio, that's why it's arbitrary. If you want to be special, pick a number that's better than all other numbers there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that was screwing the ratio width/height was the title, that no matter the new size, was the same height, thus ruining the ratio for every new size, on taking into account the -30 px the ratio now alwasy gives the same value.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A specific window size can be forced by handling the [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanging) message. You get to decide the new width and height by any algorithm you desire when the user resizes the window.

Answer (score -1):

The preferable main window size is dependable from a reason for which you create the app.
Actually, some sort of auto-size can be applied.

What I mean is:
if a main window is for displaying a video, that requires to get a preferable size of a video frame. Otherwise, if there is no specific requirement of a window size then maybe using some sort of existing examples would be valuable

The easiest way is to start command prompt console application under Windows operating system, of course the console is not centered on the screen, but nevertheless, the console has a default size that is suitable for current screen resolution

For example:
the screen on my notebook has a resolution of displaying: 1920x1220px;
and the default size of the console window is 1220x697px;
That looks very good.
Thus, the coefficient of the scaling is ~1.56.
I believe that can be used as a rule for calculating a default size of the main window in many cases.
Finally, a window caption height may be taken into account in cases when client area size is considered as essential.